# Is Android's Binder implementation always non-blocking for "void method"-calls without parameters?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-source, android-kernel

Will IPC "void method"-calls without any parameters block the current thread/process? Or will the kernel just pause the caller-process/thread until the call finishes because the called process may do further IPC callbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, depends on the definition of the specific AIDL declaration of the function. If the AIDL defines the function as one way, then it's non-blocking, otherwise it's blocking.